# Is com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry directly transportable using requestfactory?

Tags: gwt, gis, hibernate-spatial

Is com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry directly transportable using requestfactory or do i have to use a value proxy with my entityproxy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#transportable, you'd have to use a `ValueProxy`.

But it doesn't seem possible to roundtrip the geometry as there are less setters than getters (i.e. the geometry cannot be re-constructed from an empty object just by calling setters); so you'd probably have to transport the textual representation of the geometry instead or use wrappers/builders.

Comment: Yes i was referring to com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry